# How to prove that the map $T \mapsto T^{-1}$ is continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, operator-theory, banach-spaces

> Let $E$ be a Banach space. Let $\mathcal L (E)$ denote the space of all bounded linear operators on $E$ and $\text {GL} (E)$ denote the space of all bounded linear operators on $E$ with bounded inverse. Consider the map $\varphi : \text {GL} (E) \longrightarrow \mathcal L (E)$ defined by $T \longmapsto T^{-1}, T \in \text {GL} (E).$ Prove that $\varphi$ is continuous.

What I need to prove is that for a given $\varepsilon \gt 0$ there exists $\delta \gt 0$ such that whenever $\|T - T_0 \|_{\text {op}} \lt \delta$ we have $\|T^{-1} - T_0^{-1} \|_{\text {op}} \lt \varepsilon.$ I tried to write $T^{-1} - T_0^{-1} = T_0^{-1} (T_0 - T) T^{-1}.$ Then we have $$\begin{align*} \|T^{-1} - T_0^{-1} \|_{\text {op}} & \leq \|T_0^{-1}\|_{\text {op}} \|T - T_0\|_{\text {op}} \|T^{-1}\|_{\text {op}} \leq \|T_0^{-1}\|_{\text {op}} \|T - T_0 \|_{\text {op}} \left (\|T^{-1} - T_0^{-1}\|_{\text {op}} + \|T_0^{-1}\|_{\text {op}} \right ). \end{align*}$$ But this shows that $$\begin{align*} \|T^{-1} - T_0^{-1} \|_{\text {op}} \leq \frac {\left (\|T_0^{-1}\|_{\text {op}} \right )^2 \|T - T_0\|_{\text {op}}} {1 - \|T_0^{-1}\|_{\text {op}} \|T - T_0 \|_{\text {op}}} \lt \varepsilon & \iff \|T - T_0 \|_{\text {op}} \lt \frac {\varepsilon} {\|T_0^{-1}\|_{\text {op}} \left ( 1 + \|T_0^{-1}\|_{\text {op}} \right )} \end{align*}$$ which is what we set out to prove. Is the above proof ok? Please check it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your last step is not clear to me. What is the $\delta$ for given $\varepsilon$?  Otherwise this definitely should work.

Comment: @Berci sir for a given $\varepsilon \gt 0$ $$\delta = \dfrac {\varepsilon} {\|T_0^{-1}\|_{\text {op}} \left (1 + \|T_0^{-1}\|_{\text {op}} \right ) }.$$

Comment: But @Berci sir in my proof I didn't use anywhere that the underlying normed linear space is a Banach space. Is it of no importance here?

Comment: Good point. I guess it should hold for arbitrary normed spaces as well, your proof seems good.

Comment: Completeness of $E$ is important if you ask whether $\operatorname{GL}(E)$ is open in $\mathcal{L}(E)$, not for the continuity of the inversion. If $F$ is the completion of $E$, then $\operatorname{GL}(E)$ is [via the isometric embedding $\mathcal{L}(E) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{L}(F)$] a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(F)$, and as such carries the subspace topology. Hence it's a topological group.